# Singleton pattern in scala that enables easy way to use mocks

Tags: scala, unit-testing, singleton

I'm working on a use case where my applications needs a singleton object of trait `Table`. I have a implementation `TableImpl()` that will be used in development environment. However, I want to be able to switch `TableImpl()` with `MockTableImpl()` in test environment.

What is the most scala way to do this?

I can use a factory to serve out singletons of `TableImpl()`, but how does the factory make the decision of returning a `TableImpl()` or `MockTableImpl()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
trait Table {
  def size: Int
}

object TableImpl extends Table { //SINGLETON
  def size = Math.abs(-5)*11 //real logic
}
```

Some application class (it may extends `App` trait).

```
class AppContext(table: Table) {
  def run = ()
}
```

Instantiate App using singleton reference.

```
new AppContext(TableImpl).run
```

Or construct application context for test reason.

```
val mock = mock[Table]
//set mock stuff
new AppContext(mock).run
```

You are encouraged to use some `DI` like [Macwire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire), [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) or Cake pattern. My advise is to always make dependencies explicit - do not use singleton `object` name directly in class body, but inject it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *against* having a component *ask* for it's dependencies. Instead, have the creator of the component *give* it its dependencies (dependency injection or inversion of control). This is an approach that fits much better with idiomatic scala.

Just have dependencies passed as constructor parameters. That way, the class can't be constructed without valid dependencies:

```
class MyApp (table: Table) {
   ...
}

class TableImpl() extends Table // singleton

// in production
new MyApp (table = new TableImpl()) // or you can use factory or whatever

// in test (assuming scalatest and scalamock)
new MyApp (table = mock[Table])
```